# Redirecting a page using Javascript, like PHP's Header->Location

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have some code like so:

```
$('.entry a:first').click(function()
{
    <?php header("Location:" . "http://www.google.com"); ?>
});
```

I would like to know how I can achieve this using Javascript.

Comment: Since you are dealing with an anchor tag, why not just use `<a href="http://www.google.com">Link text</a>`, instead of javascript?

Comment: Good question. Bit of an odd one here. The url will be holding a few variables and when a user clicks the link, it should be seen until the next page.

Comment: @KeithDonegan can you please review and accept an answer, or update your question with some more detail

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The PHP code is executed on the server, so your redirect is executed before the browser even sees the JavaScript.

You need to do the redirect in JavaScript too

```
$('.entry a:first').click(function()
{
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
});
```

Comment: That's the way I remember learning it some time ago. I think there was some sort of issue with the browser's backwards-button if simply assigning a new value. But I think this works, too

Comment: Almost perfect. anyway to open this in a new window?

Comment: Unless output buffering was turned on, the header wouldn't even function as the JS code would be counted as output.

Comment: @KeithDonegan yes.. `window.open("http://www.google.com");` This is some pretty basic JS.

Comment: This would be exactly the last time that I'd visit your page. If a link should open in a new window, a new tab or the same/window tab should be up to the user, not the developer. But this is just my opinion and shouldn't kick off a discussion :)

Answer (score 29):

You cannot mix JS and PHP that way, PHP is rendered before the page is sent to the browser (i.e. ***before the JS is run***)

You can use window.location to change your current page.

```
$('.entry a:first').click(function() {
    window.location = "http://google.ca";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You application of js and php in totally invalid.

You have to understand a fact that JS runs on clientside, once the page loads it does not care, whether the page was a php page or jsp or asp. It executes of DOM and is related to it only.

However you can do something like this

```
var newLocation = "<?php echo $newlocation; ?>";
window.location = newLocation;
```

You see, by the time the script is loaded, the above code renders into different form, something like this

```
var newLocation = "your/redirecting/page.php";
window.location = newLocation;
```

Like above, there are many possibilities of php and js fusions and one you are doing is not one of them.